# Instead of INSERT trigger getting bypassed

Tags: java, sql-server, database-trigger

I have a table which has a column named `tripNumber` which shouldnt have a duplicate.

I know, that I can alter the table and make that column `unique` but for some reason, I cant alter the table as it's already in production. Hence I wrote the following trigger which basically does the same thing.

```
    USE [cst_abc]
GO

/****** Object:  Trigger [dbo].[checkTripNumber]    Script Date: 12/21/2019 18:37:10 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE trigger [dbo].[checkTripNumber] on [dbo].[tripDetails]
instead of insert
as 
begin
if exists(select * from [dbo].[tripDetails] where tripNumber = (select [tripNumber] from inserted i))
RAISERROR ('Trip is already there.',15,0);
else
INSERT INTO [cst_abc].[dbo].[tripDetails]
           ([tripNumber]
           ,[noW]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[someText]
           ,[totalInput]
           ,[totalOutput]
           ,[Difference]
           ,[start]
           ,[end]
           ,[StartTime]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[serverSync])
SELECT[tripNumber],[noW],[EndTime]
           ,[someText]
           ,[totalInput]
           ,[totalOutput]
           ,[Difference]
           ,[start]
           ,[end]
           ,[StartTime]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[serverSync] from inserted i
end
GO
```

It does work as expected. I wrote a small java code which basically starts a new thread and try to insert rows. What I do is to first check if a trip exists, if yes, does nothing, else inserts a new row with a particular id.

```
public static void startThread()
    {
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                showTimeInMilli("FuncA");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();
        new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                showTimeInMilli("FuncB");
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }).start();

    }

public static void showTimeInMilli(String name) throws SQLException
    {
        System.out.println("called from "+name +"Current time is "+System.currentTimeMillis());
        if(checkTripNumber(1))
        {
                System.out.println("called from "+name +" and trip exists.");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("called from "+name +" and inserting new row.");
            SqlUtil.startNewTrip(1,7,"ap1","2019-06-18 07:06:00",5,1576631560);
        }
    }
```

Point to be noted here is that, this trigger i.e to `startTrip` can be triggered from multiple source and I have seen that most of the times it gets triggered at the same time ( I store the `epoch` time for example from two sources it gets triggered at exactly `1576934304`)

**Problem**

9 out of 10 times it works expected, i.e it doesnt let a new row added but at times, it adds a duplicate `tripNumber`. Any help is highly appreciated.

Ideal Log for the above java code is :

```
called from FuncACurrent time is 1576933097423
called from FuncBCurrent time is 1576933097423
td before sendig false
called from FuncB and inserting new row.
td before sendig false
called from FuncA and inserting new row.
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Trip is already there.
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:217)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.getNextResult(SQLServerStatement.java:1655)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.doExecutePreparedStatement(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:440)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement$PrepStmtExecCmd.doExecute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:385)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7505)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2445)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeCommand(SQLServerStatement.java:191)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerStatement.executeStatement(SQLServerStatement.java:166)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.execute(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:367)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.execute(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:44)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.execute(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)
    at database.SqlUtil.startNewTrip(SqlUtil.java:45)
    at database.Hikari.showTimeInMilli(Hikari.java:122)
    at database.Hikari.lambda$0(Hikari.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
SQL Exception2 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Trip is already there.
```

Un-expected Log is :

```
called from FuncACurrent time is 1576933097323
called from FuncBCurrent time is 1576933097323
td before sendig false
called from FuncB and inserting new row.
td before sendig false
called from FuncA and inserting new row.
```

Comment: Two issues with the code: 1) race condition(check and insert are separate statements 2) check would not allow for multiple value insert `where tripNumber = (select [tripNumber] from inserted i)` this will fail when `INSERT INTO values (), ()`

Comment: *"I know, that I can alter the table and make that column unique but for some reason, I cant alter the table as it's already in production."* Then go back to the Dev environment, make the change, perform testing and then release. A `UNIQUE CONSTRAINT`/`UNIQUE INDEX` is the correct answer here. End of story. Don't use triggers to do this kind of work; especially if you don't have another index on `tripNumber` as an `INSERT` is gunna get *real* slow. Also, as this is only on `INSERT`, someone could just get around this with an `UPDATE`.

Comment: @LukaszSzozda, I understand that multiple inserts would not work in this case. I guess I will remove the trigger and make the column unique, but whats the issue here? Doesnt insert etc, lock the db for sometime, perform the operation and the release the lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The case is INSERT is separated from checking for tripNumber existence:

```
INSERT INTO [cst_abc].[dbo].[tripDetails]
           ([tripNumber]
           ,[noW]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[someText]
           ,[totalInput]
           ,[totalOutput]
           ,[Difference]
           ,[start]
           ,[end]
           ,[StartTime]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[serverSync])
SELECT[tripNumber],[noW],[EndTime]
           ,[someText]
           ,[totalInput]
           ,[totalOutput]
           ,[Difference]
           ,[start]
           ,[end]
           ,[StartTime]
           ,[EndTime]
           ,[serverSync] 
from inserted i
where NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [dbo].[tripDetails] d WHERE i.[tripNumber] = d.[tripNumber]);
```

Anyway this kind of "workaround" is not good approach and normal "UNIQUE" constraint should be introduced instead.

---

EDIT:

> **I cant alter the table as it's already in production**

How about adding unique index(technically speaking table is not altered, index is separate object):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX udx_tripDetails(tripNumber) ON [dbo].[tripDetails](tripNumber)
WITH(ONLINE = ON);
```

Comment: Hmm, the "problem" here, however, is that this won't error if a duplicate is attempted to be inserted. It'll give the "illusion" of the `INSERT` working even if no rows are (or perhaps only 2 of the 3). Plus as I mentioned, an `UPDATE` can just get around the problem; but that is a separate problem.

Comment: @Larnu Yes agree, the only correct solution is UNIQUE constraint/index

Comment: On that, I completely agree. I really dislike triggers that try to enforce constraints; they always end up having "features".

Comment: I agree that using "triggers" here might be a wrong approach and I will add Unique constraint. Nonetheless, I got to know that while `checking` if the row is there or not, another statement can itself add a new row. Will remember it.